# Scraping data from a java generated webpage with R

Tags: java, r, web-scraping

The Dutch government publicizes the subsidies it gives on a website:

http://www.hetlnvloket.nl/databank-eu-subsidiegegevens-2012#

However, it is not straighforward to get the data from the website. If you go to the site, choose 'Gemeenschappelijk Landbouw Beleid' (Common Agricultural Polici, the EU subsidy schedule) and press 'zoek' (zoek means 'search') at the bottom of the page you get a table from 100 entries. But I can't get it into R. It seems the page is generated with a JavaScript after you press 'zoek'.

My questions are:

1. How do I scrape this from the website?
2. How do I get the other 900 pages (there are a total of 90K records)

I asked the government to give me this data in XLS but they won't, for 'privacy reasons'. But this way nobody can check. I don't like that. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you are ALLOWED to scrape this data? Given what you state in 2), I'm sure you're not.

Comment: I suspect the privacy thing is someone not understanding open governance and freedom of information, both of which I think the Dutch would be usually quite good at. XLS, though? You need an API, not a proprietary file format.

Comment: It looks like the data is obtained via AJAX, which should be quite crawlable. If you are just after a snapshot of the data, have a look at import.io - their desktop crawler might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the url change, the request is usually done via ajax, or via a post-request to the same page. In this case it is done via an ajax POST-request to a certain page with some parameters. To find out what page is loaded with what parameters, open your developer console. You can do so by right-clicking in most browsers and clicking 'inspect element', or by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>. Go to the network tab and click the search button. You'll see a request in the network tab pop up. Inspect this request. You'll notice that this is a request to `/pls/feed/glb2012`. You can find the request parameters around there too.

As for the question "how" to scrape this. Use a programming language and your favorite scraping library. To suggest a library is out of the scope for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool better suited for scraping than R.  For example, Scrapy or BeautifulSoup in python, Mojolicious or Web::Scraper in perl, ...  You want to scrape with a scraping tool, output data in csv (or something similarly standard), and then get it into R.

You need to figure out what the browser-server communication is exactly.  The data is probably not *at* the url you see when you go to that page.  A quick capture in Wireshark and look at the HTTP requests will show that.

It looks like, based on your level of experience (and likely, not wanting to learn new tools just for this) you probably want to have someone do it for you.  Post it on elance, make sure whoever does it has done a bunch of scraping projects, it should take only a couple of hours max.

If you do want to do it, then follow scraping tutorials and cookbook examples, but remember to check the actual communication in Wireshark as you do that.

Comment: It's easier to watch the conversation in Firebug, or a native Net watcher built into most browsers.